# changing admob banner size dynamically

Tags: android, if-statement, admob, banner

Here is the thing, as you might know Admob has a `AdSize.*`  function, where u put `Banner` to show banner ads, and  AD_banner`  for tablet banners, what i want to do is take a screen size of a device so that i could throw it in my if statement and then put the right banner for right device, i hope i was clear enough.So anyone can tell me how can i get the screen size of device?
Thank u
//////////
Here's what i have done so far

```
     DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

       if (dm.density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,s);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.admob);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
       }
       if (dm.density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT || dm.density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW ) {
             AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,s);
             LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.admob);
             layout.addView(adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        }
        if(dm.density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)
        {
            AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_BANNER,s);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.admob);
            layout.addView(adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your layout is define in a xml, you can create one layout per screen size (layout-xlarge/mylayout.xml, layout-large/mylayout.xml, layout-normal/mylayout.xml, etc...)

More info here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Don't look at density, because, a 10.1" tablet has a medium density, but a 4.3" phone with a 480x850 resolution will have a high density. Use screen size instead (xlarge large normal small).

If you need to do it programatically, you can get the screen size with this :

```
Configuration config = activity.getResources().getConfiguration();
int screenlayout = config.screenLayout;
```

and to compare, use Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_xxx .

Answer (score 13):

The most recent AdMob SDK includes AdSize.SMART_BANNER which enables the best size matched ad for the device.

I was using an older version myself and didn't knew about this feature :D

Comment: But note that you can't currently use smart banners with AdMob Network Mediation, as you can read in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation).

Comment: I would strongly suggest avoiding smart banners for this very reason; if you later decide to mediate using an ad network that doesn't support them, your only choice would be to upgrade the app code; and you can't guarantee that all users will be using the upgraded app, so you might break your ads.

Comment: Also, smart banners are not no smart, they cannot handle device rotations, meaning that if the app is opened in landscape, after switching to portrait the ad will disappear because it doesn't fit.