# AdMob Banner Size Error When used with Autolayout

Tags: admob, swift2

I have been struggling with following problem quite a while :
I have swift project that has autolayout on I am working with any height, any width. 
I have adbanner whos height is 50 and side are pinned to super view.

when I run I get this error :

> Unable to set adSize property. Not enough space to show ad
>   with custom size, {600, 50}. Please use a size the fits the current
>   screen bounds of {320, 568}.

I read quite a few post here, either they are not using autolayout or for android : 
[AdMob Banner Size for retina display iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298646/admob-banner-size-for-retina-display-iphone)

[changing admob banner size dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953088/changing-admob-banner-size-dynamically)

[adMob | Extend Banner size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088426/admob-extend-banner-size)

[How to create an admob banner programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953075/how-to-create-an-admob-banner-programatically)

[How to specify adUnitId programmatically for AdMob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766257/how-to-specify-adunitid-programatically-for-admob)

This google link which was for android again, was somewhat helpful to shape my thinking
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner?hl=en

After reading a lot loosly related stuff. I write this line:

> adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner

Which should solved the problem as I am on iPhone and Banner is 320x50
I tried kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait too

But I am still seeing the error, and ad is not being displayed 
I thought it might be because of as its testing device 
I did following too ...

> ```
>     if debug{
>         var devices: [String] = ["fe2b6df035b7b0729ae7d33cf35d2aa9"]
>         GADRequest().testDevices = devices
>     }
>     else{
>        adBannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
>     }
> ```

But No luck. Anyone have some pointers for me.

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Comment: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33117648/how-to-change-google-ads-banner-view-ad-size-programmatically-in-ios) check out my answer and convert objective c code to swift