# how to change google ads banner view ad size programmatically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to use google ads banner view for all screen iPhone to iPad , but unfortunately iPhone screens shows me a warning like following.

Unable to set adSize property. Not enough space to show ad with custom size, {600, 50}. Please use a size the fits the current screen bounds of {320, 568}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried lot but result will be the same , so i am trying to write code as google suggest . following code i have been used to clear this issue.

bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait ;

no need to set width constant as 320 on UI interface.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this solution:

1. In Interface Builder, create a constraint Banner View.Center X = Superview.Center X
2. In Interface Builder, create a constraint Banner View.Width = 320 and Select Remove at build time
3. In code, setup the width like so: adBannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait (For Portrait)

The debugger will stop complaining for all iPhones in portrait

I hope this helps